# How can I use C# to retrieve Java data from a socket?

Tags: c#, java, .net

I want to send `BigInteger` data in socket and my friend wants to retrieve the data.
I am using Java, but my friend uses C#.

```
String str = "Hello";
BigInteger big = new BigInteger(str.getBytes);
byteToBeSent[] = big.toByteArray();
```

I am sending this byte array (`byteToBeSent[]`) through socket. And my friend wants to retrieve "Hello".

How is this possible?

Comment: Creating a BigInteger from a string like "Hello" seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

From Java, send your string using [String.getBytes(encoding)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29) and specify the encoding to match how your friend will read it (e.g. UTF-8).

This will translate your string into a byte stream that will be translatable at the C# end due to the fact that you're both agreeing on the encoding mechanism.

I'm not sure what your BigInteger mechanism is doing, but I don't believe it'll be portable, nor handle sizable strings.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, your best bet would to be use the built in Encoding classes in C#.

```
string str = "Hello";
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
```

And then send that through the socket.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use `BigInteger` to send String data? Or is that just an example?

If you want to send String data, use `String.getBytes(String encoding)`, send the result and decode it using `System.Text.Encoding`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get a [custom BigInteger class for C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163696.aspx).

But parsing "Hello" as a biginteger isn't going to work. I you want to send text, you're better of using Navaars method.

Answer (score 0):

On the C# end, you can use System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToConvert[]) to convert the received byte array back to a string.

I had thought that was some sort of Java idiom to convert a string to a byte array. It does correctly convert the string into ASCII bytes, and since BigInteger length is arbitrary, the length of the string should not be an issue.